# "constant is being redefined" with defconstant?

Tags: common-lisp

I'm reading chapter 5.2 of PAIP. And when I try define a constant using the following form, taken exactly from the book, I get the error shown below. I'm using **SBCL 1.1.14.debian** as the interpreter.  What am I doing wrong?

```
(defconstant no-bindings '((t . t))
  "Indicates pat-match success, with no variables.")
```

> The constant NO-BINDINGS is being redefined (from (T T) to ((T . T)))

Answer (score 2):

The error means that you have done a previous definition of the same name `no-bindings` with the value `'(T T)`.

For instance in the REPL you have done a definition:

```
(defconstant no-bindings '(t  t)
  "Indicates pat-match success, with no variables.")
```

and then you have redefined `no-bindings` with:

```
(defconstant no-bindings '((t . t))
  "Indicates pat-match success, with no variables.")
```

The [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcon.htm#defconstant) specifies:

> A constant defined by `defconstant` can be redefined with `defconstant`. However, the consequences are undefined if an attempt is made to assign a value to the symbol using another operator, or to assign it to a *different* value using a subsequent `defconstant`.

**Updated**

Note that in SBCL, even a double definition of the same value, for instance, writing twice in the REPL:

```
(defconstant no-bindings '((t . t))
  "Indicates pat-match success, with no variables.")
```

causes a constant redefinition error, while in other systems (I tried CCL), this does not happen. Actually this is due to the interpretation of "different value" in the above definition. The Glossary says the different is not the same, and same is not eql, and

```
 (eql '((t . t)) '((t . t)))
```

gives `NIL`, while other equality operators, as, for instance:

```
 (equal '((t . t)) '((t . t)))
```

returns `T`.

So, it seems that SBCL follows correctly the formal specification, differently from other systems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have checked my code, and don't find redefination. My code have added on my question. Could you help me to check out what cause that error?

Comment: The CLHS indirectly defines “same” to mean “same under EQL” via the Glossary: “2. (of objects if no predicate is implied by context) indistinguishable by eql.”

Comment: Note also, ALEXANDRIA:DEFINE-CONSTANT allows specification of the test predicate, which is convenient for EQUALP structures.

Comment: flingjie, it is true that in your code you don't have a redefinition, but if you recompile or reload the file this is equivalent to a redefinition.

Comment: @BRPocock, you are correct about CLHS, I changed my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A constant is per spec a value that is not suppose to be changed.. Thus you should use it for absolute certainties like `(defconstant +pi+ 3.1415927)`.

In practice it's changeable, but every function or macro where it has been used might have taken advantage of it being a constant and compiled in the actual value so changing it won't be affected by those. Thus changing a constant should be done by a complete recompile/reload of everything to make make sure it's updated.

For values that are considered constant but you might change, use [`defparameter`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/m_defpar.htm). eg. `(defparameter *no-bindings* '((t . t)) "Indicates pat-match success, with no variables.")`.